# How to show DateTime.Now into Input Box

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET Core 7.0` and tried to show `DateTime.Now` into *Input box* but did not show anything when the page was loaded.

See below all my codes.

**Data Model:**

```cs
public class DateShowVM
{
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public DateTime TranDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Action method:**

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.datenow = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));    
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TranDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="TranDate" value="@ViewBag.datenow" readonly class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="TranDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: i couldn't see anything wrong, but get sure your view call by  Index() action ,or for test delete your quotation marks in front of value prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want **ONLY** show (not editing) a date in specific format in the `<input>` tag it's easier to use `type="text"`:

```html
<input asp-for="TranDate" class="form-control" type="text" 
         value="@ViewBag.datenow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" readonly/>
```

Take to account, that when you are using the `ViewBag` the data annotations like you declared in the `DateShowVM` class are become useless. It's necessary to specify the format in the `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` method.

But when using the strongly typed view the data annotation is in the game. Therefore, it's enough to apply the required format to the property.

Define data model and pass to the view:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new DateShowVM() { TranDate = DateTime.Now };
    return View(model);
}
```

The view code:

```html
@model DateShowVM

<div class="form-group">
  <input asp-for="TranDate" class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
</div>
```

---

*There are a lot of questions on the StackOverflow about using the `input` tag with `type="date"`, but to support different date formats it's required to write the JavaScript code.*

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is for `ViewBag.datenow` may be. .NET will automatically handle this conversion of datetime format and your input format expected "dd/MM/yyyy" format. Maybe for mismatch the problem occurring.

Change your code

```
ViewBag.datenow = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

to

```
ViewBag.datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

It should resolve your issue. I think it's better to use a model to handle the data.